# How to use PHP form validation with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I love jQuery mobile, but I'm epically disappointed there's no support for form validation, not even skinning.  I'd like to use PHP for form validation... is there a way to accomplish this?  I already have all this code in place and would like to avoid rewriting it all in javascript if possible.

Is there a way I can submit the form to a URL via ajax, but return a json error message?

Any thoughts?

Comment: `and would like to avoid rewriting it all in javascript if possible`. You know jQuery is javascript right?

Comment: My form validation is currently in PHP, that's what I was referring to

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do a ajax call on the submit of the form

You can use $.ajax and .serialize() http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ to send the formdata to the server, in the callback you can do anything you want, for example highlight the elements that you return in a json error message, or when no errors move on with $.mobile.changePage

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VfhMa/14/

**Other good examples**

Submit a JQuery Mobile form via AJAX with PHP
http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2574

jQuery Mobile Form Validation (even with landscape/portrait distinction)
http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-form-validation.html